# Show tooltip when datagridview cell is selected

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

How can you show the tooltip for datagridview when cell is selected, not from mouseover but from using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've noticed, you won't be able to use the DataGridView's built in tooltip.  In fact, you will need to disable it so set your DataGridView's `ShowCellToolTips` property to `false` (it's `true` by default).

You can use the DataGridView's `CellEnter` event with a regular Winform ToolTip control to display tool tips as the focus changes from cell to cell regardless of whether this was done with the mouse or the arrow keys.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    var cell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
    var cellDisplayRect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
    toolTip1.Show(string.Format("this is cell {0},{1}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex), 
                  dataGridView1,
                  cellDisplayRect.X + cell.Size.Width / 2,
                  cellDisplayRect.Y + cell.Size.Height / 2,
                  2000);
    dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;
}
```

Note that I added an offset to the location of the ToolTip based on the cell's height and width.  I did this so the ToolTip doesn't appear directy over the cell; you might want to tweak this setting.

Comment: Important: You have to set the `ShowCellToolTips` property to `False`. I know it is stated in the answer, but I thought to give it more emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Riggs'answer is the one I used. Also, because I needed a much longer duration, I had to add this event in order to make the tooltip to dissapear.

```
private void dataGridView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.Hide(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        dgv.CurrentCellChanged += new EventHandler(dgv_CurrentCellChanged);
    }

    void dgv_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Find cell and show tooltip.
    }
```